# SO and SO Meta logos not Retina

Tags: feature-request, design

I've recently noticed that the Stack Overflow logo on both SO and Meta is not Retina-optimized.

[image]

All the rest of the site is - except for that logo at the top. As such, it makes an (otherwise) retina-optimized site feel old - the top left of the screen is where your eyes first look, and it's where your first impression comes from.

So, **please optimize the top left SO logo for the Retina display.** Thanks.

Comment: What is a Retina-Optimized logo ?

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk One that's not blurry on a Retina screen.

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk See updated post.